# Convert namespace string to a map of slices

Tags: go, validation

I am using go-validator lib,

To get the error namespace I can call:

```
ns := e.Namespace()
```

Will result something like this:

```
"Customer.customer_addresses[0].location_name"
```

And to get the error message I can call:

```
err := e.Error()
```

Will result something like:

```
"location_name is a required field"
```

Is there standard lib, utilities, or the fastest way to make this string:

```
"customer_addresses[0].location_name"
```

To become map like this:

```
{
   "customer_addresses": [
      {
         "location_name": "location_name is a required field"
      }
   ]
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi man, can you share a complete file with the sample code? I want to be sure about your struct definition, the library you used, etc.? Thanks to this way we can see the actual output and the desired one. Thanks!